# REST API Aggreggation Real time

Tags: java, php, api, rest, curl

Is there is any best way to Aggregate 100 to 200 REST API Data Source into one Single API call Real time?

Typical Example is for a HOTEL / Flight Booking Engine where we need to HIT other Multiple partners API and Return the Response Real time Fast within 2 seconds.

We need to call Multiple Different API and consolidate the Response in 1 API.

We tried Multi threading / Parallel curl and it is taking more than 50 seconds to process 50 API hits.

Any other Better Way to Optimize this and Return all the Aggregate API into 1 API within 2 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExecutorServices. if need to wait the response from other API then you can maintain a CountdownLatch.

Ref : See [ExecutorServices](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)

And [CountDownLatch](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/countdownlatch-example-in-java.html)

Comment: Girish Thanks and Any Third party Library to use?

Comment: @YongHuiShin No need any third party api if you use ExecutorService  and CountDownLatch which is in java.util.concurrent  (java JRE).